# Create informational popup / tooltip in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, popup, tooltip

The question title is kind of vague, but I really don't know what the thing is called.

[image]

I am trying to create one of those yellow informational popup things. Anyone can tell me what they're called and how I can create them?

Comment: No need to apologize - it's hard to google something when you don't know the right keyword.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That's called a tool tip. You can set the tool tip for any `NSView` using `setToolTip:`.

Comment: +1 and you can make it show up at a specific point using `addToolTipRect:owner:userData:` http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-BBCHBAHJ

Comment: You can also use Interface Builder to assign them, in the Identity Inspector.

Comment: This Api is suits to text only. Can i show an imageView as a ToolTip.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using NSTextView, you can even set an attribute for a certain range in NSTextstorage, that displays the Tooltip.
Something like:

```
[textStorage addAttribute:NSToolTipAttributeName
                    value:error.description
                    range:range];
```